# Implicit conversion not behaving as expected

Tags: scala

Do i have a misunderstanding how implciits work in Scala - given the following trait in Scala,

```
trait hasConfig {

  implicit def string2array(s: java.lang.String): Array[String] = {
    LoadedProperties.getList(s)
  }

  implicit def string2boolean(s: java.lang.String) :  java.lang.Boolean = {
    s.toLowerCase() match {
      case "true" => true
      case "false" => false
    }
  }

  var config: Properties = new Properties()
  def getConfigs : Properties = config
  def loadConfigs(prop:Properties) : Properties = {
    config = prop
    config
  }

  def getConfigAs[T](key:String):T = {
    if (hasConfig(key)) {
      val value : T = config.getProperty(key).asInstanceOf[T]
      value
    }
    else throw new Exception("Key not found in config")
  }

  def hasConfig(key: String): Boolean = {
    config.containsKey(k)
  }
}
```

Though java.util.properties contains (String, String) key value pairs, I expect the following code to work due to the implicit converstion defined,

```
class hasConfigTest extends FunSuite {
  val recModel = new Object with hasConfig
  //val prop = LoadedProperties.fromFile("test") Read properties from some file
  recModel.loadConfigs(prop)

  test("test string paramater") {
    assert(recModel.getConfigAs[String]("application.id").equals("framework"))
  }

  test("test boolean paramater") {
    assert(recModel.getConfigAs[Boolean]("framework.booleanvalue") == true) 
    //Property file contains framework.booleanvalue=true
    //expected to return java.lang.boolean, get java.lang.string

  }
}
```

However, I get the following error,

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

Why is the implcit conversion not taking care of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because casting (`asInstanceOf`) is something entirely different than implicit conversions. There are multiple ways in which you can solve this.

### Implicit conversion

If you want to use the hardcore implicit conversions magic you should rewrite you `getConfigAs` method like this:

```
def getConfig(key:String): String = {
  if (hasConfig(key)) {
    val value: String = config.getProperty(key)
    value
  }
  else throw new Exception("Key not found in config")
}
```

You will have to import the conversions into the current scope when you use `getConfig`.

```
val recModel = new Object with hasConfig
import recModel._
recModel.loadConfigs(prop)
val value: Boolean = recModel.getConfig("framework.booleanvalue")
```

### Implicit parameters

A better way would be to keep your current API, but then you will have to introduce an implicit parameter because the implementation of `getConfigAs` needs access to the conversion.

```
def getConfigAs[T](key:String)(implicit conv: String => T): T = {
  if (hasConfig(key)) {
    val value: String = config.getProperty(key)
    value
  }
  else throw new Exception("Key not found in config")
}
```

You will still need to import the necessary conversions at the use site though.

```
val recModel = new Object with hasConfig
import recModel._
recModel.loadConfigs(prop)
val value = recModel.getConfigAs[Boolean]("framework.booleanvalue")
```

### Typeclasses

A way to avoid having to import your conversions (and possibly implicitly converting all kinds of `Strings` by accident) is to introduce a new type to encode your conversions. Then you can implement the conversions in its companion object, where implicit search can find them without importing them.

```
trait Converter[To]{
  def convert(s: String): To
}
object Converter {
  implicit val string2array: Converter[Array[String]] = new Converter[Array[String]] {
    def convert(s: String): Array[String] = 
      LoadedProperties.getList(s)
  }

  implicit val string2boolean: Converter[Boolean] = new Converter[Boolean] {
    def convert(s: String): Boolean = 
      s.toLowerCase() match {
        case "true" => true
        case "false" => false
      } 
  }
}
```

Then you can change your `getConfigAs` method.

```
def getConfigAs[T](key:String)(implicit conv: Converter[T]): T = {
  if (hasConfig(key)) {
    val value: String = config.getProperty(key)
    conv.convert(value)
  }
  else throw new Exception("Key not found in config")
}
```

And use it.

```
val recModel = new Object with hasConfig
recModel.loadConfigs(prop)
val value = recModel.getConfigAs[Boolean]("framework.booleanvalue")
```

You might also want to take a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits).

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Do you have any recommendation on what would be best practice in scala? I quite like the typeclasses answer as it is similar to @mavarazy below.

Comment: Typeclasses and implicit parameters are almost always preferred. And when you need a real implicit conversion for some reason (dsl, some fancy api,...) it's also preferred to use them together with typeclasses, like `implicit def convert[T](t: T)(implicit writer: Writer[T]): String = writer.write(t)`.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversions should be defined in scope, for example in enclosing object or imported into the current scope. In your case they should be defined in scope of the `hasConfigTest` class.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits

Here's a simple reproducible example:

```
object m {
  implicit def string2boolean(s: String): Boolean = {
    s.toLowerCase() match {
      case "true"  => true
      case "false" => false
    }
  } //> string2boolean: (s: String)Boolean
  println(false || "true") //> true
  println(false || "false") //> false
}
```

Comment: If that was the problem, there would be compilation errors, not `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to say, is something like this:

```
import java.util.Properties

object LoadedProperties {
  def getList(s: String): Array[String] = Array.empty
}
object hasConfig {
  sealed trait ConfigReader[T] {
    def read(conf: String): T
  }
  implicit object BooleanConfigReader extends ConfigReader[Boolean] {
    override def read(conf: String): Boolean = conf.toLowerCase() match {
      case "true" => true
      case "false" => false
    }
  }
  implicit object ArrayConfigReader extends ConfigReader[Array[String]] {
    override def read(s: String): Array[String] = {
      LoadedProperties.getList(s)
    }
  }
  var config: Properties = new Properties()
  def getConfigs: Properties = config
  def loadConfigs(prop: Properties): Properties = {
    config = prop
    config
  }
  def getConfigAs[T](key: String)(implicit reader: ConfigReader[T]): T = {
    val prop = config.getProperty(key)
    if  (prop == null)
      throw new Exception("Key not found in config")
    reader.read(prop)
  }
}

val props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("a", "false")
props.setProperty("b", "some")
hasConfig.loadConfigs(props)
hasConfig.getConfigAs[Boolean]("a")
hasConfig.getConfigAs[Array[String]]("a")
```

Comment: This is a really good answer thank you. Can only accept one though!! Upvote!